# mount.cifs won't mount the shared folder despite both computers being able to ping each other

Tags: networking, arch-linux, windows

So I connected a windows computer and a linux computer and now I'm trying to mount a shared folder from windows to linux. I turned off the password protected sharing, allowed the folder to everyone, I am able to ping both computers back and forth. The shared folder path is `\\WindowsPC\Doc` according to windows. So under linux I run : `sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.50/Doc /mnt -o guest` but it gets stuck and has no output until I stop it with `C-c`. `sudo mount.cifs //WindowsPC/Doc /mnt -o guest` returns :

> mount error :: could not resolve address for WindowsPC: unknown error

Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: Try adding the switch username after the -o `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.50/Doc /mnt -o username=guest`.

Comment: guest must be enabled on the windows share, too.